# Let's encrypt certbot on AWS Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am new to AWS and Let's encrypt both.
I follow and article and simpley run these commands

```
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
chmod a+x certbot-auto
sudo cp certbot-auto /usr/bin/
```

Then I run this command.

```
sudo /usr/bin/certbot-auto --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com --debug
```

This gives me the error

> Sorry, I don't know how to bootstrap Certbot on your operating system!
>
> You will need to install OS dependencies, configure virtualenv, and
>   run pip install manually. Please see
>   https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contributing.html#prerequisites
>   for more info.

What does this really means?

How do I setup certbot on AWS linux?

Comment: I haven't used letsencrypt before, let me have a read for you.

Comment: are you using amazon linux

Comment: When you say "what does this really means", do you mean you don't understand what it's telling you to do? Do you know how to install OS dependencies on AWS Linux? Do you need help with the virtual environment and pip? Or something else?

Comment: There are also AWS-supplied LetsEncrypt instructions here using EPEL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt

Answer (score 8):

I have created a fresh amazon linux 2 ec2 instance and tested the following for you.

The following steps are working for me.

```
Edit the file /usr/bin/certbot-auto to recognize your version of Linux:
$ sudo vim /usr/bin/certbot-auto
find this line in the file (likely near line nearr 780):
elif [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
and replace whole line with this:
elif [ -f /etc/redhat-release ] || grep 'cpe:.*:amazon_linux:2' /etc/os-release > /dev/null 2>&1; then
Save and exit vim (type :wq to do that)
```

Reference:
[Deploying Let’s Encrypt on an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 Instance](https://medium.com/@gnowland/deploying-lets-encrypt-on-an-amazon-linux-ami-ec2-instance-f8e2e8f4fc1f)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that system requirements are met, you can find the system requirement [here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html#system-requirements).

Also [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-auto-deployment-best-practices/91979) are the best practices for certbot-auto deploment.

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to your home directory (/home/ec2-user).
- Download EPEL using the following command.    `sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm'    https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/`
- Install    the repository packages as shown in the following command.
  `sudo rpm -Uvh dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-*.rpm`
- Enable EPEL as shown in the following command. `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel*`
- Confirm that EPEL is enabled with the following command.
  `sudo yum repolist all`

### Install and run Certbot

This procedure is based on the EFF documentation for installing Certbot on Fedora and on RHEL 7. It describes the default use of Certbot, resulting in a certificate based on a 2048-bit RSA key.

`sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-apache` or `sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-nginx` For nginx.

[Source here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt)

Comment: I've tried these steps and after running `sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-apache` I get many errors such as `Error: Package: python2-requests-2.6.0-0.el7.noarch (epel) Requires: python-requests >= 2.6.0` and similar.